# In what year does Secrets of Dumbledore really take place?

Tags: fantastic-beasts, the-secrets-of-dumbledore

I have heard two different years cited for when this film takes place:

- 1928, based on a line by the character Lally telling Jacob that the events in the bank from the first movie happened "A little over a year ago".
- 1932, based on a paper briefly seen during the movie.

Either much more time passes during this movie than appears, OR one of these is a mistake. Generally, I am one to take dialogue over props, but this is an awkward situation.

Has there been any official word regarding which is the mistake and when this film takes place?

Comment: Could be a plothole.

Comment: [Wikipedia says 32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts:_The_Secrets_of_Dumbledore), we were told on set at the time it was 32 [in the Berlin scenes, didn't see any other locations]. Haven't seen it properly yet so idk about a possible plot-hole.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for that insight. I think Wikipedia is just citing the same in-universe newspaper in this case (as is HP wiki). But on-set experience is certainly valid.

Comment: I explicitly remember Lally telling jacob the event in the bank were 5 years ago, not one. Which make your question moot. I watched in english with french subtitles. So I'm pretty sure I got it right.

Comment: @dna I rewatched the film since. English with english subs. She definitely says "a little over a year ago".